# Having Trouble With Kaminari Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, pagination, rubygems, kaminari

I'm trying to paginate multiple tables with the Kaminari Gem. I've tried to do this by generating an array in my application controller, like so:

```
@paginate = %w(errors messages subscribers).page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

I've then taken `@paginate` and used it in one of my partials than renders the tables, like so:

```
<%= paginate @paginate %>
```

But I keep receiving a:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::ApplicationController#index
undefined method `page' for ["errors", "messages", "subscribers"]:Array
```

Here is the code that I've got:

**Application_Controller.rb**

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < InheritedResources::Base
protect_from_forgery
include ResourcesHelper
layout "admin"

#Setup
before_filter :set_resource_variable
before_filter :set_pagination_variable, only: :index

#Authentication
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
before_filter :authenticate_admin!

#Authorization
skip_before_filter :check_authentication

#Index
#Custom Index For Application/Index (no inheritance) 
def index
    @users = User.all
    @attributes = %w(messages subscribers)
    @paginate = %w(errors messages subscribers).page(params[:page]).per(15)
end

#Create
def create
    create! { collection_path }
end

#Update
def update
    update! { collection_path }
end


private
#Set Model Variable
def set_resource_variable
    @resource = self.resource_class
    @model = "#{@resource}".downcase.to_sym
end 

#Pagination
def set_pagination_variable
    #params[:page] ||= "1"
end

#Strong Params
def permitted_params
    attributes = attributes(@resource) + %w(user_id admin_id) + [image_pages_attributes: [:caption, image_attributes: [:image]]]
    params.permit(@model => attributes)
end
```

end

**_table.html.erb**

```
<h2><%= model %></h2> 
<% unless collection.blank? %>
<table class="sort">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <% model.attribute_names.each do |attr| %>
                <th><%= model.human_attribute_name(attr) %></th>
            <% end %>
            <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
            <% if model.name == "Error" %><th>&nbsp;</th><% end %>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%= render partial: "admin/resources/table/row", collection: collection, as: :resource, locals: {model: model}  %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**_row.html.erb**

```
<tr data-link="<%= polymorphic_path([:admin, resource]) %>">
<% model.attribute_names.each do |attr| %>
    <td><%= resource.send(attr) %></td>
<% end %>
<% if model.name == "Error" %>
    <td><%= link_to "Read", admin_error_read_path(resource.id), method: :put, remote: :true, class: "read" %></td>
<% end %>
<td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_polymorphic_path([:admin, resource]) %></td>
<td><%= link_to "Delete", polymorphic_path([:admin, resource]), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></td>
```

If you need anything else, let me know and I'll put it up.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting "page" properly.  It should always be like this:

```
paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
```

So in your example

```
@paginate = %w(errors messages subscribers).page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

What you really want is:

```
@paginate = %w(errors messages subscribers).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work im afraid. I've got the same error accept this time it's not 'Undefined Method Page' it's now 'Undefined Method Paginate'

Comment: Hmm... What version of the gem are you running? And what version of rails? What does it say when you do `bundle show` ?

Comment: "kaminari", "~> 0.15.0"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45183/discussion-between-mystic-cola-and-joe-hilton)